# Forward HTTP to HTTPS - AWS Windows Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-ec2, https, window

I have a applications running on AWS Windows and Node.js. I can access using http and https. But i need it to forward http to https if anyone access through http. 
I can think of many way, but would appreciate any advice on the best approach. The server is a EC2 instance, accessed through a load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using express, this middleware module makes it easy to enforce https: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-force-ssl

If you're using a reverse proxy in front of your app (ELB, nginx, etc), you'll need to set the trust proxy setting.

Here's a sample without the above module:

```
    // Forward all requests to HTTPS.
    // enable reverse proxy support in Express. This causes the
    // the "X-Forwarded-Proto" header field to be trusted so its
    // value can be used to determine the protocol. See
    // http://expressjs.com/api#app-settings for more details.
    app.enable('trust proxy');

    // Add a handler to inspect the req.secure flag (see
    // http://expressjs.com/api#req.secure). This allows us
    // to know whether the request was via http or https.
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      if (req.secure) {
        // request was via https, so do no special handling
        next();
      } else {
        // request was via http, so redirect to https
        console.log('Redirecting to https');
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
      }
    });
```

Complete sample app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Forward all requests to HTTPS.
// enable reverse proxy support in Express. This causes the
// the "X-Forwarded-Proto" header field to be trusted so its
// value can be used to determine the protocol. See
// http://expressjs.com/api#app-settings for more details.
app.enable('trust proxy');

// Add a handler to inspect the req.secure flag (see
// http://expressjs.com/api#req.secure). This allows us
// to know whether the request was via http or https.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.secure) {
        // request was via https, so do no special handling
        next();
    } else {
        // request was via http, so redirect to https
        console.log('Redirecting to https');
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
});

// Respond to any GET requests with our message
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.send('This is only served over https');
});

// Listen on the assigned port
var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Hello started on port ' + port);
```

Redirect only GET requests, respond with error for non-GET requests

```
  app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.secure) {
      next();
    } else if (req.method === 'GET') {
      res.redirect(`https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`);
    } else {
      res.status(401).send('Secure channel required');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks very close what I am after. Currently I get "Can't set headers after they are sent". I have been trying to put the code further up but then I get "Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined". Sorry I an quite new to node :-)

Comment: I've added a complete sample app in the answer above.  Save that as app.js then run with ``node app.js``

Comment: It worked line majic, I had to add "return" in front of redirect.. thats all. thank you

Comment: I should add that it's not a good idea to redirect non-GET requests.  If a POST call comes in and is redirected, the browser will make that redirected call as a GET.  You probably want to respond with a 401 or similar to non-GET requests.  You could do that like above.

Comment: Awesome. works like a charm.  :) especially useful when my EC2 node.js server is behind ELB.